package edu.stanford.nlp.trees.semgraph does not exist
I am trying to get the codes from this paper to run on my Linux machine. The repository can be found at https://github.com/onexpeters/PAROT. As expected of AI researchers, the project lacks basic software engineering (no build buildsystem, no dependency structure, no documentation and such) So I had to add a make-shift pom.xml for maven, and add dependencies through compile errors. I don't seem to be able to find relevant dependencies to install... Mainly the Stanford NLP Core library: It is fetched and installed properly, but the packages that authors used in their code  are still missing.
The dependencies for my made-up maven:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>
        edu.stanford.nlp
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>
        stanford-corenlp
    </artifactId>
    <version>
        3.9.2 <!--also tried 4.5.x -->
    </version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-parser -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>
        edu.stanford.nlp
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>
        stanford-parser
    </artifactId>
    <version>
        3.9.2
    </version>
</dependency>  

Compile error:
[ERROR] ...PAROT/src/nlp/ds/DependencyTree.java:[20,39] package edu.stanford.nlp.trees.semgraph does not exist


I'm not sure what you mean but: https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/edu.stanford.nlp/stanford-corenlp/versions

@khmarbaise I mean, I added the dependency, there are still missing package compile errors
